# Drawing multiple curve in one ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have this dataframe :

```
data <- data.frame(statut_matri=c("Concubins","Concubins","Concubins","Concubins","Maries","Maries","Maries","Maries","Celib","Celib","Celib","Celib"),
                      year=c("2010","2014","2018","2021","2010","2014","2018","2021","2010","2014","2018","2021"),
                      financial=c(1.5,1.4,1.3,1.2,2.5,2.4,2.3,2.2,3,1.8,1.6,1.5))
```

And I would like to plot the variable financial (y axis), with x axis being the variable year, depending on group statut_matri.
In other words, I want year in the x axis, financial in the y axis and 4 curves who represent the value of financial for each year and each group of statut_matri.

I tried this but didn't get the expected result:

```
g <- ggplot(data, aes(x = year, y=financial, colour=as.factor(statut_matri))) + 
  geom_line() 
g
```

Comment: Welcome to SO!  What result did you get, and why wasn't it what you expected?  Perhaps because your `year` is a character column?  Does `aes(x = as.numeric(year) ...` come closer to ehat you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I run it, a message is emitted that makes the right suggestion to adjust the group aesthetic. (And I get no lines.)

```r
ggplot(data, aes(x = year, y=financial, colour=as.factor(statut_matri))) + 
  geom_line() 
# `geom_line()`: Each group consists of only one observation.
# ℹ Do you need to adjust the group aesthetic?
```

So let's add `group=`. (And change to using just `factor(.)`, it's doing what we need it to.)

```r
ggplot(data, aes(x=year, y=financial, colour=factor(statut_matri), group=statut_matri)) +
  geom_line()
```

[image]

And we get three lines suggested by the data.

FYI, your year is categorical, which means the separation between x-values is not representative of the intuitive difference between them. I suggest you convert this to an `integer`. I'll pre-convert, and since you want the included years shown, I'll force the `breaks=` as well.

```r
data$year <- as.integer(data$year)
ggplot(data, aes(x=year, y=financial, colour=factor(statut_matri), group=statut_matri)) +
  geom_line() +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = ~ sort(unique(data$year)))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks ! On the second graph, the years displayed on the x axis are not correct : I only have observations for 2010, 2014, 2018, 2021. How can you specify it?

Comment: You can change that with `scale_x_continuous(breaks = ...)`, perhaps `scale_x_continuous(breaks = sort(unique(data$year)))`

Comment: @Chloe_pa I edited the second code/plot to reflect that change.

Answer (score 1):

Be aware always of the error message: it says there is only one observation per group, therefore, a line plot is inexistant. What you do is group in the aesthetics by statut_matri. You can have two options: a facet_wrap() with individual line plots per group or a simple color differentiation. I hope it helps.

Here is the image of the two possible outputs, just for you to see.

[image: Here is the image of the two possible outputs, just for you to see.]

*Option 1*

```
ggplot(data, aes(x = year, y=financial, group = statut_matri, color = statut_matri)) + geom_line()
```

*Option 2: same, but with facets dividing each specific statut_matri category*

```
ggplot(data, aes(x = year, y=financial, group = statut_matri, color = statut_matri)) + geom_line() + facet_wrap( ~ statut_matri)
```

Comment: When you present an option (1) that is the same as another answer (from 14 minutes prior), it is generally "nice" to mention that your code is not novel. The new portion of your answer is the faceting, which was not requested in the OP, so I'm a little at a loss as to the value added here.