# How to convert vector of values to concave down parabolic curve

Tags: r, quadratic

I have a vector of values 0-100.

```
values <- runif(n = 1000, min = 0, max = 100)
```

I'd like to transform these values into a concave down parabolic curve where values at the middle (approximately 50) would have new values of the max (100) and those at the low (0) and high (100) would be 0. Plotting my original vector vs the new would essentially look like the plot below. Any suggestion for how to write this equation in R?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little bit of algebra gives a quadratic (not a parabola) that goes through the points (0, 0), (50, 100) and (100, 0) as -((x-50)^2)/25 + 100.

So does

```
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(123)

tibble(
  value = runif(n = 1000, min = 0, max = 100),
  new_value = -((value - 50)^2/25) + 100
) %>% 
ggplot() +
  geom_line(aes(x = value, y = new_value))
```

[image]

give you what you want?

Comment: This is great and just what I need. What's the significance of the "/25" and can see it controls where the quadratic lands on the y-axis but why?

Comment: It's just a scale factor: it makes the curve go through the three points you specified.

Comment: Any suggestion  if I wanted my quadratic to be centered over 40 instead of 50.? I understand the quadratic would no longer be symmetric but that's what I want

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame(n=seq(1,1000))
df$v_old <- sort(runif(1000,min=0,max=100))
df$v_new <- -1/50*(df$v_old - 50) ^ 2 + 50
df %>% ggplot(aes(x=v_old,y=v_new)) + geom_line()
```

[image]

Comment: Apart from *not* going through the point (50, 100) as requested by the OP, how does this differ from the previously posted (and accepted) answer? As mentioned [elsewhere] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78068217/drawing-multiple-curve-in-one-ggplot/78068263#78068263), when you present [something] that is the same as another answer ... it is generally "nice" to mention that your code is not novel.

Comment: In addition, to ensure replicability when using `runif()`, `sample()`, `rnorm()` etc., use `set.seed()`.